# Generate sentences from keywords by adding formal word

Tags: nlp, lstm, nlg

For example, I have a list of keywords like I, hungry => output: I am hungry or I, author, poem => output: I am the author of this poem.
Can someone please suggest the simplest way to achieve this?
I am a newbie, please tell me which knowledge I must have to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am also fairly new to this, but am working on the same type of problem where I have to predict the sentence based on previous data. Like you want giving X value predict y value.

So, basically you need to create a dataset as per your requirement and once your dataset is ready you can train your model with encoder-decoder or LSTM layers.

Please find below links that may be helpful to you to fulfill your requirements. See as X and Y value input output prediction.

1. [Gmail style smart compose](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/PrithivirajDamodaran/NLP-Experiments/blob/master/Gmail_style_smart_compose_with_char_ngram_based_language_model.ipynb)
2. [Neural Machine Translation with Attention](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.13/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/nmt_with_attention/nmt_with_attention.ipynb)
3. [Sentence Prediction using LSTMs](https://github.com/irdanish11/Sentence-Prediction-using-LSTMs_aka-Language-Modeling)